# Return Optimized x coordinates to normalize/maximize area for an array of rectangles with defined y positions

Tags: javascript, algorithm, math, tessellation

I've included a code snippet that hopefully should sum things up nicely and is represented in a sort of 'Fill in the blanks' kind of state.

If it helps to understand the origin of the problem by seeing it in a larger context, what I'm ultimately doing is showing a daily view schedule on calendar on a phone, probably similar to how the calendar on your phone works.  When events begin to overlap in time, represented by the vertical y axis here I want to be able to optimize the width and positioning of those events, not overlapping them and not hiding more than I have to for the content - but when there are too many being able to indicate things are hidden.

I'm not looking for any CSS/HTML based solutions despite the sample being in javascript - the DOM structure is more or less set in stone, just looking for an algorithm that might do what I'm looking for, if it's in C++, TurboPascal, Assembly, Java, whatever doesn't really matter.  In my example expected results the more complex the scenario the results are more like rough estimates, and it comes across in the demo as well when rendering my expected results - I don't even really have a terrific method for doing the math in my head once things start getting weird.

The objective is to fill in the function `optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping = (rectangles,minimumArea,minimumWidth,xMin,xMax)=>{}`

```js
// Let's say I have an array like this of rectangles where they have set y coordinates
// Some constraints on how this array comes out: it will besorted by the yTop property as shown below, but with no secondary sort criteria.
// The rectangles difference between yBottom and yTop is always at least 15, in other words this array won't contain any rectangles less than 15 in height

const rectanglesYcoordinatesOnlyExample1 = [
{"rectangle_id":"b22d","yTop":0,"yBottom":60},
{"rectangle_id":"8938","yTop":60,"yBottom":120},
{"rectangle_id":"e78a","yTop":60,"yBottom":120},
{"rectangle_id":"81ed","yTop":207,"yBottom":222},
{"rectangle_id":"b446","yTop":207,"yBottom":222},
{"rectangle_id":"ebd3","yTop":207,"yBottom":222},
{"rectangle_id":"2caf","yTop":208,"yBottom":223},
{"rectangle_id":"e623","yTop":227,"yBottom":242},
{"rectangle_id":"e6a3","yTop":270,"yBottom":320},
{"rectangle_id":"e613","yTop":272,"yBottom":460},
{"rectangle_id":"c2d1","yTop":272,"yBottom":290},
{"rectangle_id":"e64d","yTop":274,"yBottom":300},
{"rectangle_id":"b653","yTop":276,"yBottom":310},
{"rectangle_id":"e323","yTop":276,"yBottom":310},
{"rectangle_id":"fca3","yTop":300,"yBottom":315}
]

// I want to get a result sort of like this, explanations provided, although I'm not sure if my internal calculations in my head are 100% on the further I go.  

// And I want to a run a function like so:
// optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping(rectanglesYcoordinatesOnlyExample1,(33.3 * 15),10,0,100);  
// I will make this call later but I need to hoist my expected results here to enable the mocking to work for now at the point of the function definiton for my example. (see below)
// like so I'd get a result something like this, but I start becoming less certain of what the correct result should be the more I go into fringe stuff.

const expectedResultMoreOrLessForExample1 = [
{"rectangle_id":"b22d","leftX":0,"rightX":100,"yTop":0,"yBottom":60},
{"rectangle_id":"8938","leftX":0,"rightX":50,"yTop":60,"yBottom":120},
{"rectangle_id":"e78a","leftX":50,"rightX":100,"yTop":60,"yBottom":120},
{"rectangle_id":"81ed","leftX":0,"rightX":33.3,"yTop":207,"yBottom":222}, // Three rectangles side by side with minimum Area ["81ed","b446","ebd3"] from this point
{"rectangle_id":"b446","leftX":33.3,"rightX":66.6,"yTop":207,"yBottom":222},
{"rectangle_id":"ebd3","isMax":true,"leftX":66.7,"rightX":100,"yTop":207,"yBottom":222},  // has isMax property because there would be an overlap if it tried the next result, and it can't take area away from the other rectangles
// This rectangle gets thrown out because it would be there are 3 other rectangles in that area each with the minimum area (33.3 * 15);
// {"rectangle_id":"2caf","yTop":208,"yBottom":223}, This one gets thrown out from the result the time being because there are too many rectangles in one area of vertical space.
{"rectangle_id":"e623","yTop":227,"yBottom":242,"leftX":0,"rightX":100},
{"rectangle_id":"e6a3","leftX":0,"rightX":25,"yTop":270,"yBottom":320},
{"rectangle_id":"e613","leftX":25,"rightX":35,"yTop":272,"yBottom":460},
{"rectangle_id":"c2d1","leftX":71.28,"rightX":100,"yTop":272,"yBottom":290},  // fill the remaining space since optimizing to max area would take 99% 
{"rectangle_id":"e64d","leftX":35,"rightX":61.28,"yTop":274,"yBottom":300},
{"rectangle_id":"b653","yTop":276,"yBottom":940,"leftX":61.28,rightX:71.28},
{"rectangle_id":"fca3","leftX":35,"rightX":61.28,"yTop":300,"yBottom":315}
]

// the function name is really long to reflect what it is what I want to do.  Don't normally make functions this intense

const optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping = (rectangles,minimumArea,minimumWidth,xMin,xMax)=>{
 // TODO : fill in the optimization function.
 // Code I'm looking for would be swapped in here if you wanted to make changes to demo it do it here
 if(rectangles === rectanglesYcoordinatesOnlyExample1 && minimumArea === (33.3 * 15) && minimumWidth === 10 && xMin === 0 && xMax === 100){  // Just handling the example
  return expectedResultMoreOrLessForExample1;
 } else {
  console.log('I only know how to handle example 1, as computed by a human, poorly.  fill in the function and replace the block with working stuff');
  return [];
 }
}


const displayResults = (completedRectangleList) => {
 const rectangleColors = ['cyan','magenta','green','yellow','orange']
 completedRectangleList.forEach((rectangle,index) =>{
   let newRectangle = document.createElement('div');
   newRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
   newRectangle.style.height = rectangle.yBottom - rectangle.yTop + 'px';
    newRectangle.style.top = rectangle.yTop + 'px';
    newRectangle.style.left = parseInt(rectangle.leftX)+'%';
    newRectangle.style.width = rectangle.rightX - rectangle.leftX + "%";
    newRectangle.style.backgroundColor = rectangleColors[index % rectangleColors.length];
    newRectangle.innerHTML = rectangle.rectangle_id;
    if(rectangle.isMax){
     newRectangle.innerHTML += '- more hidden';
    }
  document.body.appendChild(newRectangle);
})
}
// I am calling this function with minimum Area of 33.3 * 15, because it represents 3 min height rectangles taking up a third of the minX,maxX values, which are 0 & 100, representing a percentage value ultimately
let resultForExample1 = optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping(rectanglesYcoordinatesOnlyExample1,(33.3 * 15),10,0,100);
displayResults(resultForExample1);
```

As far as what I've tried, I start something then I kind of think of fringe cases and things get a little haywire.  Even in the expected results I've calculated in my head I think my own humanized calculations are a little off, so when evaluating this issue and looking at my expectedResult and then the rendering of it, it's a little off.  Hopefully the intent and meaning behind the `optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping()` is more or less clear.

I'm still working on potential approaches, but in the meantime seeking out the wisdom of the crowd until it comes to me.  I'm curious as to the solution, but I haven't discovered the right track.

Comment: What's the maximum allowed `y` value?

Comment: Those yTop values could in practice go up to 1440, since they each represent a minute in a day (24 *60).  The yBottomcould extend beyond 1440, which would mean an event cuts across days - but I could in theory potentially cut any yBottom down to the yMax of 1440 if it makes the solution easier. yTop has max of 1440 as is.  If those constraints can speed up the algorithm then use it, but I'm assuming the solution is similar whether or not y is finite or infinite, optimize the width of the rectangles relative to vertical space neighbors is key, depending on which vertical space the rect is in

Comment: I thought I had an easy solution, but then started to think about oddball cases. For example, here are two possible solutions for a set of four rectangles. [solution1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RE1er.png) [solution2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BBIcV.png).
Solution1 maximizes the rectangle sizes, but IMO solution2 is more aesthetically pleasing. And that's what makes the problem difficult. Algorithms have a hard time understanding aesthetics.

Comment: Ultimately this seems to be a version of the [2D bin packing problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packing_problems#Different_rectangles_in_a_rectangle). That link leads to another link with code that may be useful to you.

Comment: @user3386109 I definitely think your comments are pretty insightful and would merit an answer, as it looks better than what I've got.  I appreciate the scientific reasoning as well with the 2D Bin packing problem, as I guess it's got some complexity to it as I suspected there might be some heady math behind it that eludes me at the moment, but I think your implementations are very good compared to where I'm at right now aesthetically. Be curious as to how the code works behind those images if you don't mind sharing?

Comment: @ chairmanmow I finally got around to it. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The algorithm in this answer attempts to arrange rectangles inside a fixed-width bounding box. Input to the algorithm is an array of rectangles whose `topY` and `bottomY` are specified. The algorithm computes the `leftX` and `rightX` for each rectangle. Rectangles are sized and positioned to avoid overlap. For example, the image below shows 7 rectangles that have been arranged by the algorithm. In region 1, the maximum overlap is 2, so the rectangles are drawn half width. Region 2 has no overlap, so the rectangle is full width. And region 3 has overlap 3, and therefore rectangles are one-third the width of the bounding box.

[image]

The algorithm has three major steps:

1. Fill the `eventQueue` based on the information in the input array.
   Each rectangle spawns two events: an `EVENT_START` with the `topY`, and
   an `EVENT_STOP` with the `bottomY`. The `eventQueue` is a priority
   queue, where the priority is based on the three values that define
   an event (evaluated in the order shown):

   - `y`: lower `y` values have priority.
   - `type`: EVENT_STOP has priority over EVENT_START.
   - `rectID`: lower `rectID` values have priority.
2. Search for the end of a region while:

   - storing the events into a `regionQueue`. The `regionQueue` is a simple FIFO, which allows the events to be processed a second time,
     after the extent of the region has been determined.
   - keeping track of the `maxOverlap` (which is limited by a function parameter). The `maxOverlap` determines the width of all
     rectangles within the region.
3. Drain the `regionQueue` while computing the X values for each
   rectangle in the region. This part of the algorithm employs an array
   called `usedColumns`. Each entry in that array is either `-1`
   (indicates that the column is not in use) or a `rectID` (indicates
   which rectangle is using the column). When an `EVENT_START` is popped
   from the `regionQueue`, a column is assigned to the rectangle. When
   an `EVENT_STOP` is popped from the `regionQueue`, the column is returned to the unused (-1) state.

The input to the algorithm is an array of rectangles. The `topY` and `bottomY` values of those rectangles must be filled by the caller. The `leftX` and `rightX` values must be initialized to -1. If the X values are still -1 when the algorithm finishes, the rectangle could not be assigned a location because the `overlapLimit` was exceeded. All the other rectangles have a full set of coordinates, and are ready to be drawn.

```
typedef struct
{
    int topY;       // input parameter, filled in by the caller
    int bottomY;    // input parameter, filled in by the caller
    int leftX;      // output parameter, must be initially -1
    int rightX;     // output parameter, must be initially -1
}
stRect;

typedef struct
{
    int y;          // this is the 'topY' or 'bottomY' of a rectangle
    int type;       // either EVENT_START or EVENT_STOP
    int rectID;     // the index into the input array for this rectangle
}
stEvent;

enum { EVENT_START, EVENT_STOP };

void arrangeRectangles(stRect *rectArray, int length, int overlapLimit, int containerWidth)
{
    stQueue *eventQueue  = queueCreate();
    stQueue *regionQueue = queueCreate();

    // fill the event queue with START and STOP events for each rectangle
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        stEvent startEvent = {rectArray[i].topY, EVENT_START, i};
        queueAdd(eventQueue, &startEvent);
        stEvent stopEvent  = {rectArray[i].bottomY, EVENT_STOP, i};
        queueAdd(eventQueue, &stopEvent);
    }

    while (queueIsNotEmpty(eventQueue))
    {
        // search for the end of a region, while keeping track of the overlap in that region
        int overlap = 0;
        int maxOverlap = 0;
        stEvent event;
        while (queuePop(eventQueue, &event))   // take from the event queue
        {
            queueAdd(regionQueue, &event);     // save in the region queue
            if (event.type == EVENT_START)
                overlap++;
            else
                overlap--;
            if (overlap == 0)                  // reached the end of a region
                break;
            if (overlap > maxOverlap)
                maxOverlap = overlap;
        }

        // limit the overlap as specified by the function parameter
        if (maxOverlap > overlapLimit)
            maxOverlap = overlapLimit;

        // compute the width to be used for rectangles in this region
        int width = containerWidth / maxOverlap;

        // create and initialize an array to keep track of which columns are in use
        int usedColumns[maxOverlap];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++)
            usedColumns[i] = -1;

        // process the region, computing left and right X values for each rectangle
        while (queuePop(regionQueue, &event))
        {
            if (event.type == EVENT_START)
            {
                // find an available column for this rectangle, and assign the X values
                for (int column = 0; column < maxOverlap; column++)
                    if (usedColumns[column] < 0)
                    {
                        usedColumns[column] = event.rectID;
                        rectArray[event.rectID].leftX = column * width;
                        rectArray[event.rectID].rightX = (column+1) * width;
                        break;
                    }
            }
            else
            {
                // free the column that's being used for this rectangle
                for (int i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++)
                    if (usedColumns[i] == event.rectID)
                    {
                        usedColumns[i] = -1;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }

    queueDestroy(eventQueue);
    queueDestroy(regionQueue);
}

void example(void)
{
    stRect inputArray[] = {
        {  0,150,-1,-1},
        { 30,180,-1,-1},
        {180,360,-1,-1},
        {360,450,-1,-1},
        {420,540,-1,-1},
        {450,570,-1,-1},
        {480,540,-1,-1}
    };
    int length = sizeof(inputArray) / sizeof(inputArray[0]);
    arrangeRectangles(inputArray, length, 3, 100);
}
```

Note: I make no claims about the validity of this code. Thorough review and testing is left as an exercise for the reader.

---

[@chairmanmow](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3934988/chairmanmow) has graciously translated the algorithm to javascript to save time for others looking for a javascript solution. Here is that translation:

```js
const topZero = 0;
const parent = i => ((i + 1) >>> 1) - 1;
const left = i => (i << 1) + 1;
const right = i => (i + 1) << 1;

class PriorityQueue {

  constructor(comparator = (a, b) => a > b) {
    this._heap = [];
    this._comparator = comparator;
  }

  size() {
    return this._heap.length;
  }

  isEmpty() {
    return this.size() == 0;
  }

  peek() {
    return this._heap[topZero];
  }

  push(...values) {
    values.forEach(value => {
      this._heap.push(value);
      this._siftUp();
    });
    return this.size();
  }

  pop() {
    const poppedValue = this.peek();
    const bottom = this.size() - 1;
    if (bottom > topZero) {
      this._swap(topZero, bottom);
    }
    this._heap.pop();
    this._siftDown();
    return poppedValue;
  }

  replace(value) {
    const replacedValue = this.peek();
    this._heap[topZero] = value;
    this._siftDown();
    return replacedValue;
  }

  _greater(i, j) {
    return this._comparator(this._heap[i], this._heap[j]);
  }

  _swap(i, j) {
    [this._heap[i], this._heap[j]] = [this._heap[j], this._heap[i]];
  }

  _siftUp() {
    let node = this.size() - 1;
    while (node > topZero && this._greater(node, parent(node))) {
      this._swap(node, parent(node));
      node = parent(node);
    }
  }

  _siftDown() {
    let node = topZero;
    while (
      (left(node) < this.size() && this._greater(left(node), node)) ||
      (right(node) < this.size() && this._greater(right(node), node))
      ) {
      let maxChild = (right(node) < this.size() && this._greater(right(node), left(node))) ? right(node) : left(node);
      this._swap(node, maxChild);
      node = maxChild;
    }
  }
}

const rectangles = [{
  rectID: "b22d",
  "yTop": 0,
  "yBottom": 60,
  "leftX": -1,
  "rightX": -1
},
  {
    rectID: "8938",
    "yTop": 60,
    "yBottom": 120,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e78a",
    "yTop": 60,
    "yBottom": 120,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "81ed",
    "yTop": 207,
    "yBottom": 222,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "b446",
    "yTop": 207,
    "yBottom": 222,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "ebd3",
    "yTop": 207,
    "yBottom": 222,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "2caf",
    "yTop": 208,
    "yBottom": 223,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e623",
    "yTop": 227,
    "yBottom": 242,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e6a3",
    "yTop": 270,
    "yBottom": 320,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e613",
    "yTop": 272,
    "yBottom": 460,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "c2d1",
    "yTop": 272,
    "yBottom": 290,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e64d",
    "yTop": 274,
    "yBottom": 300,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "b653",
    "yTop": 276,
    "yBottom": 310,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "e323",
    "yTop": 276,
    "yBottom": 310,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  },
  {
    rectID: "fca3",
    "yTop": 300,
    "yBottom": 315,
    "leftX": -1,
    "rightX": -1
  }
];

let eventQueue = new PriorityQueue((a, b) => {
  if (a.y !== b.y) return a.y < b.y;
  if (a.type !== b.type) return a.type > b.type;
  return a.rectID > b.rectID;
})
let regionQueue = []; // FIFO
const EVENT_START = 0;
const EVENT_STOP = 1;

const queueAdd = (queue, toAdd, type, priority) => {

  return queue.push(toAdd);
}


const queuePop = (queue) => {
  return queue.pop();
}

const queueDestroy = (queue) => {
  return queue = [];
}

const optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping = (rectArray, length, overlapLimit, containerWidth) => {
  // fill the event queue with START and STOP events for each rectangle
  for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    let startEvent = {
      y: rectArray[i].yTop,
      type: EVENT_START,
      index: i
    };
    eventQueue.push(startEvent);
    let stopEvent = {
      y: rectArray[i].yBottom,
      type: EVENT_STOP,
      index: i
    };
    eventQueue.push(stopEvent);
  }
  while (eventQueue.size()) { // queueIsNotEmpty(eventQueue)
    // search for the end of a region, while keeping track of the overlap in that region
    let overlap = 0;
    let maxOverlap = 0;
    let event;
    while (event = eventQueue.pop()) { // take from the event queue
      queueAdd(regionQueue, event); // save in the region queue
      if (event.type === 0) {
        overlap++;
      } else {
        overlap--;
      }
      if (overlap === 0) { // reached the end of a region
        break;
      }
      // if we have a new maximum for the overlap, update 'maxOverlap'
      if (overlap > maxOverlap) {
        maxOverlap = overlap;
      }
    }
    // limit the overlap as specified by the function parameter
    if (maxOverlap > overlapLimit) {
      maxOverlap = overlapLimit;
    }

    // compute the width to be used for rectangles in this region
    const width = parseInt(containerWidth / maxOverlap);

    // create and initialize an array to keep track of which columns are in use
    let usedColumns = new Array(maxOverlap);
    for (let i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++) {
      if (usedColumns[i] == event.rectID) {
        usedColumns[i] = -1;
        break;
      }
    }
    // process the region, computing left and right X values for each rectangle
    while (event = queuePop(regionQueue)) {
      if (event.type == 0) {
        // find an available column for this rectangle, and assign the X values
        for (let column = 0; column < maxOverlap; column++) {
          if (usedColumns[column] < 0) {
            usedColumns[column] = event.rectID;
            rectArray[event.index].leftX = column * width;
            rectArray[event.index].rightX = (column + 1) * width;
            break;
          }

        }
      } else {
        // free the column that's being used for this rectangle
        for (let i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++)
          if (usedColumns[i] == event.rectID) {
            usedColumns[i] = -1;
            break;
          }
      }
    }

  }
  return rectArray;
}


const displayResults = (completedRectangleList) => {
  const rectangleColors = ['cyan', 'magenta', 'green', 'yellow', 'orange']
  completedRectangleList.forEach((rectangle, index) => {
    if (rectangle.leftX > -1 && rectangle.rightX > -1) {
      let newRectangle = document.createElement('div');
      newRectangle.style.position = 'absolute';
      newRectangle.style.height = rectangle.yBottom - rectangle.yTop + 'px';
      newRectangle.style.top = rectangle.yTop + 'px';
      newRectangle.style.left = parseInt(rectangle.leftX) + '%';
      newRectangle.style.width = rectangle.rightX - rectangle.leftX + "%";
      newRectangle.style.backgroundColor = rectangleColors[index % rectangleColors.length];
      newRectangle.innerHTML = rectangle.rectID;
      if (rectangle.isMax) {
        newRectangle.innerHTML += '- more hidden';
      }
      document.body.appendChild(newRectangle);
    }

  })
}
let results = optimizeLeftAndRightXStartPointsForNormalizedRectangleAreaWithoutOverlapping(rectangles, (rectangles.length), 3, 100);
console.log('results ' + JSON.stringify(results));
displayResults(results);
```

Below is the java code

```java
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ArrayList<stRect> inputArray = new ArrayList<>();
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 0,150,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 30,180,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 180,360,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 360,450,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 420,540,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 450,570,-1,-1));
    inputArray.add(new stRect( 480,540,-1,-1));
    arrangeRectangles(inputArray, inputArray.size(), 3, 100);

    for(int i = 0;i<inputArray.size();i++){
        System.out.println(inputArray.get(i).topY+" "+inputArray.get(i).bottomY+" "+inputArray.get(i).leftX+" "+inputArray.get(i).rightX);
    }
}

private static void arrangeRectangles(ArrayList<stRect>rectArray, int length, int overlapLimit, int containerWidth){
    int EVENT_START = 0, EVENT_STOP = 1;

    PriorityQueue<stEvent> eventQueue = new PriorityQueue<>(new MyComparator());
    Queue<stEvent> regionQueue = new LinkedList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        stEvent startEvent = new stEvent(rectArray.get(i).topY,EVENT_START, i);
        eventQueue.add(startEvent);
        stEvent stopEvent = new stEvent(rectArray.get(i).bottomY,EVENT_STOP, i);
        eventQueue.add(stopEvent);
    }

    while (!eventQueue.isEmpty()){
        int overlap = 0;
        int maxOverlap = 0;
        stEvent event;

        while (!eventQueue.isEmpty()){ // take from the event queue
            event = eventQueue.remove();

            regionQueue.add(event);    // save in the region queue

            if (event.type == EVENT_START)
                overlap++;
            else
                overlap--;

            if (overlap == 0)          // reached the end of a region
                break;

            if (overlap > maxOverlap)
                maxOverlap = overlap;
        }

        // limit the overlap as specified by the function parameter
        if (maxOverlap > overlapLimit)
            maxOverlap = overlapLimit;

        // compute the width to be used for rectangles in this region
        int width = containerWidth / maxOverlap;

        int usedColumns[] = new int[maxOverlap];
        for (int i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++)
            usedColumns[i] = -1;

        while (!regionQueue.isEmpty()){
            event = regionQueue.remove();

            if (event.type == EVENT_START) {
                // find an available column for this rectangle, and assign the X values
                for (int column = 0; column < maxOverlap; column++){
                    if (usedColumns[column] < 0) {
                        usedColumns[column] = event.rectID;
                        rectArray.get(event.rectID).leftX = column * width;
                        rectArray.get(event.rectID).rightX = (column+1) * width;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }else {
                // free the column that's being used for this rectangle
                for (int i = 0; i < maxOverlap; i++){
                    if (usedColumns[i] == event.rectID)
                    {
                        usedColumns[i] = -1;
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    eventQueue.clear();
    regionQueue.clear();
    }
}

public class MyComparator implements Comparator<stEvent> {

    @Override
    public int compare(stEvent o1, stEvent o2) {
        if(o1.y<o2.y)
            return -1;
        if(o1.y>o2.y)
            return 1;

        if(o1.type == 0 && o2.type ==1)
            return 1;
        if(o1.type == 1 && o2.type ==0)
            return -1;

        if(o1.rectID<o2.rectID)
            return -1;
        if(o1.rectID>o2.rectID)
            return 1;

        return 0;
    }
}

class stEvent {
    int y;          
    int type;       
    int rectID;

    stEvent(int y, int type, int rectID) {
        this.y = y;
        this.type = type;
        this.rectID = rectID;
    }
}

class stRect {
    int topY;       // input parameter, filled in by the caller
    int bottomY;    // input parameter, filled in by the caller
    int leftX;      // output parameter, must be initially -1
    int rightX;

    stRect(int topY, int bottomY, int leftX, int rightX) {
        this.topY = topY;
        this.bottomY = bottomY;
        this.leftX = leftX;
        this.rightX = rightX;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful - I'm going to convert it to javascript and take it for a whirl - will do the upvote/acceptance on the answer after conversion and maybe link to js plunkr if it works out.  JS adaptation coming

Comment: I believe I was able to implement this and javascript and added an answer with that code.  This is the accepted answer, however, as it has all the logic/explanations in it.  If you want to attach the JS code to your answer, feel free and I'll delete that, but I thought it would help the question in long run to ultimately post the JS code in the context of the original example.  Again, thanks for your help, and if you notice anything off in my JS version, please let me know.

Comment: @chairmanmow Thanks! I wasn't sure that I would be able to understand the translation, given that I'm not familiar with javascript. But the translation was actually very easy to understand, and everything looked right to me. Cheers!

Comment: I'm glad it makes sense and you were able to include and I was able to port (my C++ is rusty), going to pull my answer as the consolidated version is ideal.   Cheers to you as well!